# Equal Sized Voronoi Cells minimize mean error/distance

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry

Suppose I have $N$ objects $x_1, x_2, ..., x_N$, where $N$ is a large integer number.

Suppose I have $M$ representation points: $y_1, ..., y_M$ where $M < N$.

Consider the quantity $$S = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N d(x_i, \psi(x_i))$$

where $\psi(x_i) $ is equal to $y \in \{y_1, ..., y_M \}$ such that $d(x_i,y) \leq d(x_i, y_k)$ for all $k \in \{1,..., M \}$.

The set of $x_i$'s mapped to a particular $y$ is called its Voronoi cell. Suppose I am trying to minimize $S$ by choosing $y_1, ..., y_M$. Is it true that equal sized, disjoint Voronoi cells is like conducive to minimization?

In a research problem I am working on, I encounter an object like $S$ which I have to lower bound. I find that I can easily give the desired lower bound if I assume equal sized, disjoint Voronoi cells condition. But I want to make sure there's no loss of generality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of variations of this problem depending on metrics used and precise details of the objective function. The most common and clearly related formulation is [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) which involves the using the squared Euclidean distance in the objective function you have given (unlike the [facility location problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facility_location_problem) which tend to optimize the maximum distance of any of the points).

For the analogous continuous problem (where rather than summing over $N$ discrete points, the objective integrates over a continuous set), optimal solutions are characterized by [centroidal Voronoi tessellations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroidal_Voronoi_tessellation) and as the number $M$ of representation points increases, the optimum tend to equal sized hexagons [1].

However, getting a lower bound on your error quantity that you describe is going to require more information about the the $N$ objects you describe. If these points are naturally grouped into $M$ tight clusters, the optimal solution can be arbitrarily small and the sizes of the Voronoi cells are just based on the locations of these clusters which may involve a very non-uniform distribution.

[1] *Newman, Donald J.*, [**The hexagon theorem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TIT.1982.1056492), IEEE Trans. Inf. Theory 28, 137-139 (1982). [ZBL0476.94006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0476.94006).